What I have done wrong in this merge sort algorithm in java
class FirstClass {
    public static void divide(int[] arr) {
        if(arr.length == 1) {
            return;
        }

        int mid = arr.length/2;

        int[] leftHalf = new int[mid];
        int[] rightHalf = new int[arr.length - mid];

        for(int i = 0; i < mid; i++) {
            leftHalf[i] = arr[i];
        }
        for(int i = mid; i < arr.length; i++) {
            rightHalf[i - mid] = arr[i];
        }

        divide(leftHalf);
        divide(rightHalf);

        merge(arr, leftHalf, rightHalf);
    }

    public static void merge(int[] arr, int[] leftHalf, int[] rightHalf) {
        int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

        while(i < leftHalf.length && j < rightHalf.length) {
            if(leftHalf[i] < rightHalf[j]) {
                arr[k] = leftHalf[i];
                i++;
            } else {
                arr[k] = rightHalf[j];
                j++;
            }
            k++;
        }

        while(i < leftHalf.length) {
            arr[k] = leftHalf[i];
            k++; i++;
        }

        while(j < rightHalf.length) {
            arr[k] = rightHalf[j];
            k++; j++;
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {1,3,6,8,3,0,6};

        divide(arr);
    }
}

I was writing this merge sort algorithm which is working fine but it was printing something off like:-
[3, 6]
[1, 3, 6]
[3, 8]
[0, 6]
[0, 3, 6, 8]
[0, 1, 3, 3, 6, 6, 8]
It is printing the correct sorted array at the last but was also printing some more arrays and I don't know how to fix this.

Use a debugger to follow the execution of your program, which should show where/when it does something wrong, from which you can determine why, and then how to fix it.

check the location of the println() call....

There are more efficient algorithms described on the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation. Most libraries use a hybrid of insertion sort and bottom up merge sort, such as timsort.

The multiple lines that you see in the output are due to the System.out.println placed inside the merge() method.
Every time a merge operation occurs during the algorithm, it will print the merged array in the output.
To print only the final sorted array, you have to move the System.out.println to the main method, after the divide() method has been called.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1, 3, 6, 8, 3, 0, 6};

    divide(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); // [0, 1, 3, 3, 6, 6, 8]
}


The extra arrays that are being printed are a result of the System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); statement within your merge method. This line causes the program to print the array every time the merge method is called, which happens multiple times as the algorithm sorts the array step by step.
To resolve this issue, you should remove or comment out the line that prints the array in the merge method. Instead, you can keep the print statement in the main method so that it only displays the final sorted array once all the sorting is complete.
